# Python: list of dictionary to pd dataframe (Twitter API)

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, twitter

I collected tweet data by using Twitter API academic track. One column is a list of dictionary about referenced tweet unique ids like this.

| No | Referenced_tweets |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1212086431889313792'}] |
| 2 | [{'type': 'quoted', 'id': '1345063319540002817'}, {'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1345066320761655296'}] |
| 3 | [{'type': 'retweeted', 'id': '1344718164974833667'}, {'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1211798476062908422'}] |

I want to transform this data like below.

| No | replied_to | quoated | retweeted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1212086431889313792 |  |  |
| 2 | 1345066320761655296 | 1345063319540002817 |  |
| 3 | 1211798476062908422 |  | 1344718164974833667 |

If I use "json_normalize", it results in the error message (TypeError: string indices must be integers). How can I do with Python?

Comment: Can you provide original json reply of this example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (let me know if you need explanation of the code):

```
def f(l):
    a={'replied_to':'', 'quoted':'', 'retweeted':''}
    x=pd.DataFrame(l)
    x=x.set_index('type')
    x=x.T
    x=x.reset_index(drop=True)
    x=x.to_dict(orient='records')
    a.update(x[0])
    return a

df['Referenced_tweets_2'] = [f(k) for k in df['Referenced_tweets']]

result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df['Referenced_tweets_2'].to_list())
    
print(result)
```

Output:

```
            replied_to               quoted            retweeted
0  1212086431889313792
1  1345066320761655296  1345063319540002817
2  1211798476062908422                       1344718164974833667
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was more difficult to solve without your help than my expectation. How can I do if I have null rows? In this case, I got the error message, "DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Comment: Just remove the rows with NULL, as this will not affect the result:  `df=df[pd.notna(df.Referenced_tweets)]`